# Why was Serefina Pekkala's daemon changed?

Tags: his-dark-materials

In *His Dark Materials* Episode 4 on BBC/HBO we are introduced to Kaisa, the daemon of the Queen witch Serafina Pekkala. He appears as a

> gyrfalcon.

However, in the books his form is settled as a

> snow goose

Does anyone know why this was changed?

Comment: Almost certainly a directorial decision. If you’ve ever seen [original form] move before, they can appear a bit comical. So it might be that the [new form] was considered more appropriate tone. I don’t have any sources to back this up but there are online discussions that feel similarly.

Comment: I'm looking for solid evidence, but many people on reddit suggest that the CGI photo-real goose looked silly when it was talking, but again, I haven't found a source that actually states this...

Answer (score -2):

Probably easier (and cheaper) to render from a CGI standpoint. The His Dark Materials show is very stingy with their daemon representations and often handwave things by saying daemons don't often interact with people their humans don't know. 
A quick google search shows that a snow goose is a mostly white bird while a gyrfalcon has much more feather detail. While I'm not a CGI expert, it stands to reason that a white bird is easier to render than one with a lot of detail.

Comment: Hello again! SE sites often requires more factual answers with sources to help prove what the answer actually is. It's not that in some cases, an educated guess with some proof can't be an accepted answer, but the rules of the site try to push for fact-based answers as it serves as a pool of credible resources. Right now your answer looks more like a comment. Once you have sufficient reputation, you will be able to use the comments section. Here's a link to take the site tour: https://movies.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Thank you for the response. Yes, I was in the no-comment limbo period for a while but now I think I'm good to go. I'll make sure to do more factual answers from now on.

Comment: No worries. It takes time to learn how to use the site and anyone can have a bad day! You can always edit your answers too, should you feel the need to improve it! :)

Comment: Your whole reasoning is that the goose is easier to render, but the show actually uses the falcon.